# Input box to search for word and then copy row to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have copied and changed loads of VBA to try and suit it for my spreadsheet and
I have managed all the filtering, copy paste, create graph stuff but am having trouble (I'm new to VBA coding).

In sheet1 I have a list of all scrap reasons (filtered largest to smallest).
I need to search sheet2 (loads of detail) for all instances of the top 5 scrap reasons in sheet1 and then copy the whole row/s of sheet 2 to sheet3.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: So... what's the *specific problem* you're having? What have you tried, where are you stumped? Have you searched for `InputBox` and `Range.Find`?

Answer (score 0):

If I have to search for a value in a known row, I use something like this:
`l_locate_value_row`

These are its arguments:

`target` value I am looking for, e.g. vityata

`target_sheet` sheet I am looking at (should be with the vba_name)

`Optional l_col As Long = 1` column, in which I am looking

`Optional l_values_found As Long = 1` if I am looking for the second value, and not the first one, I would give 2.

Thus `l_locate_value_row("vityata",tbl_main)` would return the first row, where `vityata` is found. If the value is not found, it returns `-1`.

```
Public Sub Decrement(value_to_decrement, Optional l_minus As Long = 1)

    value_to_decrement = value_to_decrement - l_minus

End Sub

Public Function l_locate_value_row(target As String, target_sheet As Worksheet, Optional l_col As Long = 1, Optional l_values_found As Long = 1) As Long

    For Each my_cell In target_sheet.Range(target_sheet.Cells(l_col, 1), target_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, l_col))

        If target = my_cell Then
            If l_values_found = 1 Then
                l_locate_value_row = my_cell.Row
                Exit Function
            Else
                Call Decrement(l_values_found)
            End If
        End If
    Next my_cell

    l_locate_value_row = -1

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I am completely new to VBA so all I have been doing is using the record facility and coping some code and then modifying it from previous posts.

Comment: @Matts Mug. I need a VBA to search through sheet 1. It finds the first scrap code ie SHRINKAGE then finds all instances of it on sheet 2 , then pastes all instances if SHRINKAGE onto sheet 3. Then does the same for the next scrap code OVERMAKES. But only on the top 5 Scrap Codes not for all.

Comment: I have tried to post some code here but it didn't work?